# ElasticSearch sorting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

ElasticSearch Version: 1.3.2

I am trying to sort simple collection but no matter what I try it just ignore sorting to me...

```
{
"query":{
  "filtered":{
     "query":{
        "match_all":{

        }
     },
     "filter":{
        "bool":{
           "must":[
              {
                 "terms":{
                    "status":[
                       "active",
                       "featured"
                    ]
                 }
              }
           ]
        }
     }
  }
},
"sort":[
  {
     "price_cents":{
        "order":"asc"
     }
  }
 ]
}
```

I've noticed in my mapping I have auto_boost = true

```
{
 "items" : {
  "mappings" : {
    "item" : {
      "dynamic" : "false",
      "_all" : {
        "auto_boost" : true
      },
    "properties" : {         
      "price_cents" : {
        "type" : "integer"
      },          
      "status" : {
        "type" : "string"
      },
      "title" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "boost" : 10.0,
        "analyzer" : "snowball"
      }
     }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

this attribute has been added automatically by https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails gem which I use:

```
mappings :dynamic => false do
  indexes :title, :analyzer => 'snowball', :boost => 10.0
  indexes :status     
  indexes :price_cents, :type => :integer, :index => 'not_analyzed'
end
```

I wonder is the "auto_boost": true the reason of sort ignore? I can't find the correct way how to turn it to false and check...

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, it is kind of related to the current bug with .records (https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails/issues/206), because of it does not paginating correctly I used temporary this construction 

    `@paginates_items = Item.search(params).page(params[:page]).per(60).results
    item_ids = @paginates_items.collect(&:id)
    @items = Item.where(:id => item_ids)`

but I forgot that where(:id => items_id) completely break the order...